# Python: How to remove a list containing Nones from a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have something like this:

```
myList = [[1, None, None, None, None],[2, None, None, None, None],[3, 4, None, None, None]]
```

And if any of the lists in the list have 4 Nones, I want to remove them so the output is:

```
myList = [[3, 4, None, None, None]]
```

I tried using:

```
for l in myList:
    if(l.count(None) == 4):
        myList.remove(l)
```

But that consistently only removes half of them, even though I know the if statement is executing correctly resulting in this:

```
[[2, None, None, None, None], [3, 4, None, None, None]]
```

I managed to get it to work using this, but it can't be right:

```
for l in myList:
    if(l.count(None) == 4):
        del l[0]
        del l[0]
        del l[0]
        del l[0]
        del l[0]

myList = list(filter(None, myList))
```

What's a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance. I'm using python 3.3.

Comment: Your for loop didn't work because you changed the list you were iterating through.  **Never** do that.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Good to note. I'm still suprised it consistently  removed half. I could get it to work by running it through, which would remove half, then running it through again, which would remove half of those, and then on and on until they were all gone though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it as:

```
my_new_list = [i for i in myList if i.count(None) < 4]

[OUTPUT]
[[3, 4, None, None, None]]
```

The problem is that you are modifying your list while iterating through it. If you want to use that kind of loop structure, do it as this instead:

```
i = 0
while i < len(myList):
    if(myList[i].count(None) >= 4):
        del myList[i]
    else:
        i += 1
```